# I am having trouble connecting my app to Mongo Atlas

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am following the documentation and based off what I read I am doing it right. I am connecting to my Mongo Atlas server. The server connects and I am able to connect to the `DB` and the `Collection`. Yet the `DB` and the `Collection` are not being passed to the `db object`.

I have tried console logging the values and refactored my logic and yet still no solution.

```
// MongoDB Connection Setup
let db = {};
let MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;

let uri = process.env.MONGODB_CONNECT_URL;
let client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });

client.connect(err => {
  assert.strictEqual(null, err);
  console.log('Connected Successfully to MongoDB!');

  db.client = client.db("cosmosdb");
  db.collection = client.db('cosmosdb').collection('cosmos');

  console.log("Database Values: ", db) // This actually returns values

  return db;
});

console.log('Database: ', db); // Not returning values

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

let server = app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
  console.log(`Express server listening on port: `, server.address().port)
});

server.db = db;
```

When I `console.log` `db` I am expecting to see

```
Database: {
 client: // values
 collection: // values
}
```

yet this is what I am getting back

```
Database: {}
```

Answer (score 0):

*EDITED*

Is your `uri` assigned like below? (`mongodb+srv`)

```
let uri = `mongodb+srv://${dbUser}:${dbPwd}@${dbHost}/test?retryWrites=true`;

let client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });
```

Comment: This is what I got in the console ```the options [dbName] is not supported
Database:  {}```

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. `{ dbName }` option available on `mongoose` only. I've updated an answer.

Comment: mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>!@cluster0-g5flo.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority

Answer (score 0):

There is a parameter you are missing on the connect() call, you have "err", but it should be (err, client). So for me it looks as follows:

```
var db = {};
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

//Use connect method to connect to the Server
MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGODB_CONNECT_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function (err, client) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  db.client = client;
  db.collection = client.db('newswatcherdb').collection('newswatcher');
  console.log("Connected to MongoDB server");
});
```

Comment: mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>!@cluster0-g5flo.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority